# ntp + ntp loose synchronize each time in 5:00 morning

Tags: linux, redhat, ntp, ntpd, date

we have a very strange behavior

we have 12 Linux redhat machines - redhat 7.x

two of these VM servers are loosing the time synchronize each day at 5:00 in the morning

after we restart the chronyd , then sync return to normal

but what could be the reason for this strange behavior ?

```
systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-07-12 20:49:43 UTC; 2 days ago
 Main PID: 971 (chronyd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/chronyd.service
           └─971 /usr/sbin/chronyd
```

Comment: Please run `chronyc -n sources; chronyc -n tracking; grep chronyd /var/log/messages|tail -n 50` as root before you restart `chronyd`, and post the output here or in a public pastebin.

Comment: ok I will , since its VM machines , do you think - that need to make sure any "sync VM's clock with the host platform" features are switched off.?

Comment: First, configure any hypervisor hosts to sync to the same NTP service. A difference large enough to disturb chrony should be fixed.

Comment: @shalom: Yes, make sure sync with host is off.